# How to quantize a signal by using of uencode and than udecode properly

Tags: matlab, math, signal-processing

I'm trying to quantize the signal with amplitude A (which can be less than 1).

```
u = uencode(y, N);
            d = udecode (u, N);
```

"Not enough input parameters" it says to me.

I was tried do this without using od udecode function.

```
        y = this.y;
        maxy = max(y);
        u = uencode(y, N, maxy, 'signed');
        u = double(u);
        p = u / max(u);
        d = p * maxy;
        this.yQ = d;
        this.QErr = this.y - d;
```

But this way is reconstructs the signal badly.

Comment: You might have noticed this already, but you're using `decode`, not `udecode` - `udecode` works fine with your sample for me.

Comment: Sorry, it's misprint. Quantization error is above zero in 90 % points. Like quantized signal is always rounds to lower level, or it is  shifted to bottom by some value